# Where to place shared test annotation/code when using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using `pytest` to write some unit tests and I have some tests that can only be run when the tests are running in cloud under some special runtime (Databricks cluster).

I want to automatically skip these tests when I run the tests locally. I know how to find if I'm running locally or not programmatically.

This is my project structure.

```
.
├── poetry.lock
├── poetry.toml
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── pkg1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── conftest.py
    │   ├── module1.py
    │   ├── module2.py
    │   ├── test_module1.py
    │   ├── test_module2.py
    │   └── utils
    │       ├── aws.py
    │       └── common.py
    └── pkg2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ...
```

test_module1.py:

```py
from pkg1 import module1
from common import skip_if_running_locally

def test_everywhere(module1_instance):
   pass # do test..

@skip_if_running_locally
def test_only_in_cloud(module1_instance):
   pass # do test..
```

common.py:

```py
import pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
running_locally = my_spark is None or \
                  my_spark.conf.get('spark.app.name') != 'Databricks Shell'

skip_if_running_locally = pytest.mark.skipif(running_locally, reason='running locally')
```

And I do the same in `test_module2.py` to mark tests that should be skipped locally.

- I don't really like to put this in `common.py` because it contains the common application code (not test code).
- I thought about putting it in a base class, but then it has to be a Class attribute (not `self.` instance attr).
- If I put it in a `test_common.py` then it'll be picked up by pytest as a file containing test cases.
- If I put it in `conftest.py` how do I import it? `from conftest import skip_...` ?

What is the right way of doing this? Where do I store common code/annotations dedicated to testing and how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `conftest.py` is the place to put common test logic. There is nothing wrong with using util/common modules, but the `conftest.py` has two advantages:

1. It is executed automatically by pytest.
2. It is the standard place, so developers would often check it.

With that said, I believe that you can use the [approach mentioned here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/markers.html#marking-platform-specific-tests-with-pytest) to have custom markers enabled/disabled according to the environment.

Your tests would look like so (note that there is no import, just using the `locally` vs `cloud` markers):

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.locally
def test_only_runs_locally():
    pass


@pytest.mark.cloud
def test_only_runs_on_the_cloud():
    pass


def test_runs_everywhere():
    pass
```

Then inside the `conftest.py` you enable/disable the proper tests:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import pytest

ALL = set("locally cloud".split())
my_spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
running_on = "locally" if (
        my_spark is None
        or my_spark.conf.get('spark.app.name') != 'Databricks Shell'
) else "cloud"

# runs before every test
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    # look for all the relevant markers of the test
    supported_platforms = ALL.intersection(mark.name for mark in item.iter_markers())

    if supported_platforms and running_on not in supported_platforms:
        pytest.skip(
            f"We're running on {running_on}, cannot run {supported_platforms} tests")
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you see any problem if we move the variable `running_on` outside the function and make it global? As it's not going to change from test to test.

Comment: There is no problem to move `running_on` outside of the method